# Searching a lists items against a another lists subset items

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the best way to do a search on 2 lists.  I've explored many post here that suggest using things like `any()` or `all()` or regex... I do have it functioning now, but I use this type of search a lot and I really would like to be doing this right.

```
SearchList = ['blah-1.2.3.tar.gz', 'blah-1.2.4.tar.gz', 'blah-1.2.5.tar.gz']
BaseList = ['blah-1.2.3', 'blah-1.2.4']
```

I would like to search the BaseList for the `'1.2.3'`, `'1.2.4'`, and `'1.2.5'` in the items of `SearchList`. I have been using a `for` loop within a `for` thing but I would like something cleaner that would use pythons list comprehension/generator expression, and `any()` or some other regex type solution.

Comment: please post your current solution ... but it sounds like this is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't want my solution... I was asking for any suggestions that didn't include a 'for within a for' type solution.

Comment: I would suggest using a regex to only get the comparable/to-be-searched strings and do the search/compare with python's `set()`

Comment: Thanks Joran for the tip about codereview.stackexchange.com just checked it out and signed up...  Looks very cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
[a for a in SearchList if a[:-7] in BaseList]
```

The a[:-7] will strip the .tar.gz at the end, the rest is basic list comprehension. It will return a list of elements from SearchList that correspond to elements from BaseList.

Comment: Perfect.  Is there a way to also grab what doesn't exist in BaseList?

Comment: I was using something like a[:-7] but a bit more complex as I don't always know blah. What is this called btw? And where can one find info on it?

Comment: Python's slice notation, you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Comment: What is what called? The [:-7] bit? That's using slice notation. The brackets indicate an index, like you'd use to query a list or a dict (essentially, a String is just a list of chars), the colon indicates a range, and the number is the index you want. A negative number counts from the right instead of the left. For example, for `x = "abcdefg"`, `x[0] == "a"`, `x[0:2] == "ab"`, `x[2:] == "cdefg"`, `x[:2] == "ab"`, `x[-3] == "e"`,`'x[-3:-1] == "efg"`, `x[-3:] == "efg"`, `x[:-3]=="abcd"`

Comment: In case your Searchlist has many different types of compressed files you can do a.replace('.zip', '').replace('.tar', '').replace('.gz', '') etc. Assuming you won't have one of those as part of the filename (like 'myfile.zipfoobar.zip') which would be weird anyway. Regex will get you a perfect check.

Comment: No sorry I didn't mean slice notation but the rest of it.

Comment: The rest of it is a simple list comprehension: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

[f(x) for x in somelist] is how you use it (in its simplest form). So for instance if you want to add 3 to every element of [1,2,3] you can do [x + 3 for x in [1, 2, 3]]. You can also add a condition, pending on which your f(x) result will or will not be part of the returned list, for instance [x + 3 for x in [1, 2, 3] if x != 2] == [4, 6]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, take advantage of the fact that [str.startswith](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) accepts a tuple argument

```
t = tuple(BaseList)
[x for x in SearchList if x.startswith(t)]
```

Comment: I tried [x for x in SearchList if not x.startswith(tuple(BaseList))] and yes that works fine as well. It might be a little (just...) slower than the one with slice notation.